# Access row data in jqGrid custom formatter

Tags: jquery, formatting, jqgrid

We have a grid with datatype json.

We have the following custom formatter:

```
function opsFormatter (cellvalue, options, rowObject){
    '<a title=MA href=javascript:showDialog(' + rowObject[5] + ')>MA<a>' + '&nbsp;&nbsp;';
}
```

Instead of `rowObject[5]` is there any object notation where we can specify the actual column name ("account")?  Ie: `rowObject.account`.

This is the grid definition:

```
$("#grid-pos").jqGrid({
    colNames:['Product', 'Type','Expiry', 'Put Call', 'Strike', 'Account','Long','Short', 'Open Qty', 'LTD', 'Operations'],
    colModel :[
               {name:'product', index:'product', width:75, sortable:false},
               {name:'type', index:'type', width:50, align:'right', sortable:false},
               {name:'expiry', index:'expiry', width:60, align:'right',stype:'select', searchoptions:{dataUrl:'expiry_select.htm'}, sortable:false},
               {name:'putCall', index:'putCall', width:65, sortable:false},
               {name:'strike', index:'strike', sorttype: 'float', width:70, sortable:false},
               {name:'account', index:'account', width:70, sortable:false},
               {name:'long', index:'long', width:55, align:'right', sortable:false},
               {name:'short', index:'short', width:55, align:'right', sortable:false},
               {name: 'openQty', index:'openQty', width:80, align:'center', formatter:closeoutFormatter, sortable:false},
               {name:'LTD', index:'LTD', width:65, align:'right', sortable:false},
               {index:'operations', width:105, title:false, align: 'center', formatter:opsFormatter, sortable:false}
               ],
               pager: '#div-pos-pager',
               caption: 'Positions'
});
```

??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems for me absolute correct behavior. The value of the parameter `rowObject` is **object** having properties with the same names as defined in the 'name' property of the `colModel`. The property `account` is one from there. I suppose that the misunderstanding come from the following part of the documentation of the [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_formatter#definition_and_parameters):

> rowObject - is a row data represented
>   in the format determined from datatype
>   option. ... If we have datatype:
>   json/jsonstring - the rowObject is
>   array, provided according to the rules
>   from jsonReader

Probably the word ***array*** follows to misunderstanding. In JavaScript `rowObject.account` can be used as `rowObject["account"]`, but one can't use `rowObject[5]` to access the `account` property of `rowObject`. It is just not clear written sentence in the documentation. If you are a native English speaker you can reformulate the text so that it will has no misunderstandings. The documentation is wiki and any person can change any text.

Comment: What I was trying to say is that `rowObject[5]` DOES work but `rowObject["account"]` and `rowObject.account` to NOT work.  What I'd like is to be able to use those last two variants..

Comment: Is it because we're using `loadOnce:true`?  Maybe this causes an issue as this setting causes the grid datatype to be `local`..  the documentation mention something about object notation only being available for the JSON datatype..

Comment: @Marcus: In my examples I can use notation like `rowObject.account`. You should post the test JSON data and more full `jqGrid` code which can be used to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Oleg is there an example you have somewhere which I could look at?

Comment: @Marcus: yes, of cause. Look at http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jsonfromsvc1.htm for example. But I know already the reason **why** we have different results. All depend on the format in which you post the data. If you use XML format of JSON with `repeatitems: false` every row the data has properties and `rowObject` should be indexed by names. If you post compact data as array of strings (for the standard jsonReader) then the `rowObject is the array of the current row and you should use [int] to access the property.

Comment: @Marcus: You can write a small function which get index of `colModel` which convert name to the index. See https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.base.js#L2933 as an example. The code fragment convert `colname` to `pos`.

Comment: Thanks Oleg, makes sense.  We do use the compact data as an array of strings..   I will try out your idea for the convert function, good idea!

Comment: For that function, how would I modify `$($t.p.colModel)` to refer to `mygrid`?

Comment: @Marcus: Yes in programs which I write I try to make data, which will be send between the server and clients, more compact. So I use always JSON data as array of strings. In other cases I use jqGrid to get show local XML log file in more readable form. In the case the data has named property.

Comment: @Marcus: `$t.p.colModel` is the same as `$("#grid-pos")[0].p.colModel`  or probably `mygrid[0].p.colModel` in your case. It is of cause better to save this in a local variable to access it more quickly inside the loop. `var cm = myGrid.getGridParam("colModel");` is another way to get `mygrid[0].p.colModel`

Answer (score 0):

You can get with this code for second index

```
rowObject.childNodes[2].textContent
```