# The afterInsertRow : function(ids) method is not executing when I use gridview:true

Tags: jqgrid

When I set **gridview** to **true** (gridview:true) in our jqGrid to increase the performance of jqGrid, the method like **afterInsertRow**, or other similar methods are not executed.
Following is the code of my jgGrid:

```
jQuery("#displaylistGrid").jqGrid({
    url: contextRoot + '/StandardProxy/displayListService?userRole='+
         userRole+'&userName='+userName+'&userId='+userId+
         '&duration='+displayDuration+'&wicNo='+wicNo+
         '&displayName='+dlDisplayName+'&displayNameArr='+displayNameArr+
         '&pointValue='+pValue+'&locationId='+locId+'&locationCode='+
         locCode+'&serviceType=forecast',
    datatype: 'json',
    colNames: ["CM Name", "Display ", "Loc. Pt.","Max. Ben." ,"Display Name",
               "Items w/Fcst", "Units", "Sales $", "Profit $", "GP%", "Units",
               "Sales $", "Profit $", "GP%","Hidden","Hidden1","Hidden2",
               "Start Date and End Date", "Hidden4"],
    colModel: [
        { name: "cm_name",      index: "cm_name",     sorttype: "text", width: 120,
          resizable: true },
        { name: "ds_location",  index: "ds_location", sorttype: "text", width: 120,
          resizable: true },
        { name: "ds_symbol",    index: "ds_symbol",   sorttype: "text", width: 50,
          align: "center",      resizable: true },
        { name: "ds_benchMark", index: "ds_benchMark",sorttype: "text", width: 50,
          align: "center",      resizable: true },
        { name: "ds_name",      index: "ds_name",     sorttype: "text", width: 230,
          resizable: true },
        { name: "ds_ItemFrcst", index: "ds_ItemFrcst",sorttype: "int",  width: 60,
          align: "center",      resizable: true,
          unformat: addDemoninatorSortingFormatter },
        { name:"ds_units_promo",index:"ds_units_promo",sorttype:"float",width: 85,
          align: "right",       unformat : spaceFormatter },
        { name:"ds_sales_promo",index:"ds_sales_promo",sorttype:"float",width: 95,
          align: "right",       unformat : spaceFormatter },
        { name: "displaylistGrid_ds_profit_promo",
          index: "displaylistGrid_ds_profit_promo",
          sorttype: "float",    width: 95,             align: "right",
          unformat : spaceFormatter },
        { name:"ds_gp_pct_promo",index:"ds_gp_pct_promo",sorttype:"int",width: 50,
          align: "right",       unformat : spaceFormatter },
        { name: "ds_units_per_store_week",
          index: "ds_units_per_store_week",            sorttype:"float",width: 85,
          align: "right",       unformat : spaceFormatter },
        { name: "ds_sales_per_store_week",
          index: "ds_sales_per_store_week",
          sorttype: "float",    width: 90,             align: "right",
          unformat : spaceFormatter },
        { name: "ds_profit_per_store_week",
          index: "ds_profit_per_store_week",
          sorttype: "float",    width: 90,             align: "right",
          unformat : spaceFormatter },
        { name: "ds_gp_pct_per_store_week",
          index: "ds_gp_pct_per_store_week",
          sorttype: "float",    width: 40,             align: "right",
          unformat : spaceFormatter  },
        { name: "hidden1",      index: "hidden1",      sorttype: "int",
          align: "center",      hidden: true },
        { name: "hidden2",      index: "hidden2",      sorttype: "text",
          align: "center",      hidden: true },
        { name: "hidden3",      index: "hidden3",      sorttype: "int",
          align: "center",      hidden: true },
        { name:"forecast_dates",index:"forecast_dates",sorttype: "text",
          align: "center",      hidden: true },
        { name: "hidden4",      index: "hidden4",      sorttype: "text",
          align: "center",      hidden: false }
    ],
    onSelectRow: function(ids){ 
        //checkDisplayDetail();
        //setDefaultValuesToTheSortingParams();
        var dropDownVal = document.getElementById("displayDetailSelection").value;
        var subTabName = document.getElementById("detailSubTabName").value;
        if(subTabName=="Active")
            dropDownVal = document.getElementById("displayDetailActiveSelection").value;
         reLoadDisplayDetailData(ids,'forecast',dropDownVal,subTabName);
    },
    afterInsertRow : function(ids) {  // shows custom tooltip
        var customToolTip = jQuery("#displaylistGrid").getCell(ids,'ds_name') +
                     " -- " + jQuery("#displaylistGrid").getCell(ids,'hidden4');
        $("#displaylistGrid").setCell(ids,'ds_name', '','',{title:customToolTip}); 
    }, 
    gridComplete : function(){
        if($("#isForecastedSalesGridLoaded").val()=="no"){
            $("#jqgh_displaylistGrid_ds_profit_promo").click();
        }
        else{
            $("#isForecastedSalesGridLoaded").val("no");
        }
    },
    onSortCol : function(){
        $("#isForecastedSalesGridLoaded").val("yes");
    },
    width: 983,
    rowNum: 999,
    height: eval(heightOfDispListGrid()+7),
    toolbar: [true, "top"],
    viewrecords: true,
    treeIcons: {leaf: "ui-icon-document-b"},
    treeGrid: true,
    treeGridModel: 'nested',
    ExpandColumn : 'Description',
    ExpandColClick: true,
    loadonce:false,
    refresh : true,
    shrinkToFit: true,
    gridview:true,         
    sortorder:"asc",
    sortname:"displaylistGrid_ds_profit_promo"
});
```

Following is the code of **afterInsertRow** method:

```
afterInsertRow : function(ids) {  // shows custom tooltip
    var customToolTip = jQuery("#displaylistGrid").getCell(ids,'ds_name') + " -- " +
                        jQuery("#displaylistGrid").getCell(ids,'hidden4') ;
    $("#displaylistGrid").setCell(ids,'ds_name', '','',{title:customToolTip}); 
},
```

The preceding code is used to show customize tool tip. Please suggest me what I am doing wrong.

Please help me

Thanks,
DISMGMT

Answer (score 4):

The sense of the usage of `gridview:true` is following. In the "gridview" mode the most grid contain will be created **as a string**. To be exactly one builds an array of substrings with HTML markup for every grid row, one creates one string from the string array with respect of `join('')` and only then one creates an DOM object represented the grid. It improves the performance not only because of better working with the long strings (`join('')`), but because of reducing working with DOM objects which is much slowly as working with strings.

So I recommend you not use `afterInsertRow` at all. Instead of that you can successfully do the same with respect of the following code

```js
var myGrid = jQuery("#displaylistGrid");
var ids = myGrid.jqGrid('getDataIDs');
for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    var id=ids[i];
    var customToolTip = myGrid.jqGrid('getCell',ids,'ds_name') + " -- " +
                        myGrid.jqGrid('getCell',ids,'hidden4');
    myGrid.jqGrid('setCell',ids,'ds_name', '','',{title:customToolTip});
}
```

which you can include in the `gridComplete` or `loadComplete`.

The best performance you will archive using [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter) for the column `ds_name` where you want to set the custom tooltip. The implementation is pretty simple because your custom formatter will receive as the `rowObject` parameter the row of the server data in the same form like it will be received from the server (as array or as an object). The properly `hidden4` will be immediately accessible (I recommend you to read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036751/access-row-data-in-jqgrid-custom-formatter/4037912#4037912) for more details).

**UPDATED**: The answer is very old. jqGrid provides many alternative implementation ways which are much better from the performance point of view. Every change on the page follows browser [reflow](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/reflow). So the usage of `setCell` in the loop is not effective. Much better is the usage of `cellattr` or `rowattr` and to continue to use `gridview: true` which advantages are described in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12519858/315935).

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7408355/315935) demonstrates very effective way to set `title` on the cell using `cellattr` instead of `setCell` used in the current answer. [Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12180842/315935) provide one more common example to use `cellattr`. To set attributes of the rows of the grid one can use `rowattr` callback. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10531680/315935) for the code example.

Answer (score 2):

[Note: this event does not fire if gridview option is set to true](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents&s%5B%5D=complete)

I had similar problem, after reading jqgrid's wiki I thought to give link to document if anyone else faces same problem.