# Adding a CSS class to a column

Tags: jqgrid

How can you add your own class to an column within jqgrid. As I see the html input elements are getting class "FormElement". I need to add an class to a particular column. I found this http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/cell-tooltip-1/#p21526, but it I am not sure whether it is the most convenient way to achieve this? I mean to go through all rows and cells and then manually change a class property - it seems to be an overhead for such "simple" task.

**UPDATE**

I want to add class because I want to use the functionality of this multiselect widget http://quasipartikel.at/multiselect/. This widget works through defined classes. That's why.

Answer (score 24):

Probably you need to use [classes](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:colmodel_options) property for the corresponding column.

I am not sure that it's what you need because you wrote about `FormElement` class existing in *form*. In the case you have to use [beforeShowForm](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events) callback of the form editing for example to add class to the input field of the corresponding field of the edit form. The id of the fields in the form are the same as the `name` property of the corresponding column of `colModel`.

If you really need to add class attribute to the cells of one column you have one more possibility: defining `cellattr` callback for the column of `colModel`. The way could be practical if you need to add the class *not for all cells of the column*. You can test some conditions based on the row content and set the class only if the condition take place. For example the usage of `classes:'ui-state-error-text ui-state-error'` will set corresponding two classes (`ui-state-error-text` and `ui-state-error`) on *all* cells on the column. On the other side the callback function

```js
cellattr: function(rowId, val, rawObject) {
    if (parseFloat(val) > 200) {
        return " class='ui-state-error-text ui-state-error'";
    }
}
```

allows you to set the class only if the cell value is higher as 200. I don't used `rawObject` in the above callback and so one could remove the optional parameter. I added it in the callback only to remind you that one can use the parameter to access to the values from *another* columns of the row. So you can implement even more complex scenarios in `cellattr`.

As the result one can get the grid like on the following picture:

[image]

**UPDATED**: If you need to add `class` on the input field of the edit forme you can additionally use`dataInit` callback of [editoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editoptions). In the case the usage will be very simple. You can do for example the following:

```js
editoptions: {
    dataInit: function (domElem) {
        $(domElem).addClass("ui-state-highlight");
    }
}
```

As the result you will get the edit form like

[image]

The demo you can find [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/addclasstocolumn.htm).

Comment: Thank you Oleg for a such comprehensive answer, I think that beforeShowForm is more appropriate in my case, because I need it only in form editing.

Comment: @Anatoliy: You are welcome! Probably the usage of `dataInit` is more practicable for you: see the **UPDATED** part of my answer.

Comment: Yes, it works fine. It really looks to be a shortest way to achieve this. Thanks a million! It was also great to see, that there are at least 3 ways to solve the problem.

Answer (score 8):

There is a `classes` colmodel option that does just what you need. From the [jqGrid documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:colmodel_options):

> **classes**
>
> string
>
> This option allow to add classes to the column. If more than one class will be used a space should be set. By example `classes:'class1 class2'` will set a class1 and class2 to every cell on that column.
>
> In the grid css there is a predefined class ui-ellipsis which allow to attach ellipsis to a particular row. Also this will work in FireFox too.

Comment: Thank you Justin, I did not know this option. As I said I knew that it should be something special for this.