# jqGrid adding a class to column by function

Tags: class, function, jqgrid

There's similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12180718/adding-a-class-to-column), but using `cellatrr` for whole column is quite overloaded. I know there's `classes` attribute, but it can be only set by static text. I would like to use a function instead like:

```
$("#jqgrid").jqGrid({ 
...
colModel:
[
{
name:'a',
index:'a',
classes: function() {
return (a < b ? "ui-state-error" : "ui-state-highlight");
}
]
});
```

Any ideas? Of course without modding jqGrid core :)

Comment: So you want a class on a cell or on a column if a value is found?

Comment: It's a example. I wonder is any way to pass function in "classes" method instead of static text

Comment: But do you want the whole column to have the class applied or just the cell? I am asking so I can answer your question....

Comment: @Mark: I would like to add class to whole column. Currently I'm doing it by cellatrr method but it takes to much time to do by each cell in col.

Answer (score 0):

```
'title'=>'Name',
'name'=>'name',
'classes'=>'your class'
```

may be you can useful. check below link

http://guriddo.net/documentation/php/_2v70w5p2k.htm