# How to add class to a cell in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have the following colModel,

```
    colModel:[
                        {name:'alertid',index:'alertid', width:0, align:'left', sortable:false,hidden:true, resizable:false},
                        {name:'name',index:'name', width:12, sortable:false,  resizable:false, classes:'colCell'},
                        {name:'alerttype',index:'alerttype', width:0, align:'left', sortable:false, hidden:true, resizable:false}
                ],
```

and the class:

```
    .colCell {
            padding-left: 15px
        }
```

But the class is not being applied to the cell.

What am I doing wrong? Is the 'classes' option only available from certain versions?

The jqgrid that I am using is 4.1.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is the priority of applying CSS styles. If you would open demo like youth in Internet Explorer, starts Developer Tools by pressing of <kbd>F12</kbd> and then choose the cell (by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>) where the `colCell` was not applied you will see something like the following

[image]

So **more specific CSS rule** on `.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td` overwrite your CSS rule. So you need just change your rule to for example

```css
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td.colCell {
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```

Now it will applied as expected. See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/AddClassToColumn1.htm) (column "Clients" has left padding 15px):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is another solution to the coloring: [Adding a CSS class to a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12180718/adding-a-class-to-column)

If the 'classes' parameter you want to use, you might need to! 'Important' but use:

http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/jqgrid-set-a-fixed-background-color-for-an-entire-column/