# How to do JqGrid Cell Editable false

Tags: jqgrid

In jqGrid how to do particular column value's cell editable true..I have a one row.Row has a four column.In that I want two column's Cell editable true and two columns cell editable false..What should I do?? give me a solution on this problem

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your question then you can use `cellattr` to set `"not-editable-cell"` class depend on the value in the column. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12180842/315935) for the corresponding code example.

Comment: Actually, i have no condition over cell. I want only first and second cell of first row editable, not third cell and also not all other rows. Please guide.

Comment: @Priya: You can examine the `rowId` (the second parameter of `cellattr`) and set "not-editable-cell" on the cell. You should include such `cellattr` callback in the columns of `colModel` which you want protect for editing. You should always identify the row by id and not by position (you wrote about the " first row"). You should think about sorting. After resorting the same row can have another position.

Comment: Thanks Oleg. I don't require sorting in grid. so not to worry for that.

Comment: But, using rowId , how i can identify that this is the first row and first cell only?

Comment: @Priya: You should post the demo or at least the JavaScript code with test data which you use. I think that there are basis misunderstanding how jqGrid work. You have to include *id* of every row in the input data. In the way you identify the item of data or the row. Only if you fill the grid in a wrong way then jqGrid will generate ids of the rows automatically as 1,2,3,...