# How to add a style class in jqGrid Td using asp.net c#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jqgrid

I want Conditionaly change style of td in jqGrid, i tried lots of example but not worked, i think i am doing something wrong, please view my code and help me to find out correct code.

My Code is

```
$(function () {

    $("#dataGrid").jqGrid({
        url: 'client.aspx/load_Conversation',
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'POST',

        serializeGridData: function (postData) {
            return JSON.stringify(postData);
        },

        ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },
        loadonce: false,
        reloadGridOptions: { fromServer: true },
        colNames: ['Conversation', 'adminStatus'],
        colModel: [{ name: 'Conversation', index: 'message', width: 245 }, { name: 'adminStatus', index: 'isAdmin' }, ],
        gridComplete: function () {
            var ids = jQuery("#dataGrid").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
            for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
                var status = jQuery("#dataGrid").jqGrid("getCell", ids[i], 'adminStatus');

                if (status == "False") {
                    $j('#' + ids[i]).removeClass("ui-widget-content");
                    $j('#' + ids[i]).addClass("ChangeStyle");
                }
            }
        },
        viewrecords: true,
        gridview: true,
        jsonReader: {
            records: function (obj) { return obj.d.length },
            root: function (obj) { return obj.d },
            repeatitems: false,
            caption: 'Live chat with us'
        }
    });
    $("#dataGrid").hideCol("adminStatus");
    $("#dataGrid").jqGrid('setGridHeight', 240);
});
```

My Code behind is

```
   public static List<Dictionary<string, object>> load_Conversation()
    {
        WebService wb= new WebService();
        DataTable dt = wb.Get();
        System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        Dictionary<string, object> row;
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            row = new Dictionary<string, object>();

            row.Add("Conversation", dr["messgae"]);
            row.Add("adminStatus", dr["isAdmin"]);
            rows.Add(row);
        }
        return rows;
    }
```

Comment: Which version of jqGrid you use? Which fork of jqGrid you use ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)? You use `reloadGridOptions: { fromServer: true }` option existing only in free jqGrid. Do you really use free jqGrid 4.9.2 or not? You use `repeatitems: false` property in `jsonReader`. Is it really corresponds the format of the server response?

Comment: I just copied code from net, can you please tell me, how can i get jqGrid version info. thanks

Comment: You can't just copy code because of possible breaking of license agreement. You can open `jquery.jqgrid.min.js` or `jquery.jqgrid.src.js` file and see the version of jqGrid in the comments at the beginning of the file. You can install free jqGrid from [GitHub](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid),  [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/free-jqGrid), [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/free-jqgrid) or [bower](http://bower.io/search/?q=free-jqgrid). You can use direct URLs described [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs).

Comment: Could you include the server response which you use or include the source code of `load_Conversation`? You try to add `ChangeStyle` CSS style. Which CSS rule you defines for the class? You use `index` different as `name` in `colModel`. Why? Your server code can give the answer. One will see whether it's a bug or the requirement.

Comment: Which CSS rule you defines for the class? Which version of jqGrid you use? You need to open jquery.jqgrid.min.js or jquery.jqgrid.src.js file and see the version of jqGrid and the license in the comments at the beginning of the file. You should additionally write short comment after changing the text of your question. I could see occasionally that you added the code of `load_Conversation` to your question.

Comment: if you want to style just td then add #dataGrid tr td { background-color: #e9e9e9: } in style

Answer (score 1):

If I correcly understand format of data returned from the server you should remove `gridComplete`, remove `index` properties from `colModel` and to use `cellattr` in `adminStatus` if you need to change the style of `<td>` elements in `adminStatus`:

```
colModel: [
    { name: 'Conversation', width: 245 },
    { name: 'adminStatus', cellattr: function (rowId, val) {
         if (val === "False") {
             return " class='ChangeStyle'";
         }
     }}
]
```

You can see an example of very close usage of `cellattr` in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12180842/315935).

It could be important **how** you defines the CSS rule on `ChangeStyle` class. If you will don't see the expected results you have to include the definition of CSS rule of `ChangeStyle` class and the version of jqGrid which you use.

Comment: .ChangeStyle { background-color:Red;} and i am using 4.1.1 version.

Comment: @user2695786: You should use `.ui-jqgrid .ChangeStyle  { background: red; }` or `.ui-jqgrid .ChangeStyle  { background-color: red; background-image: none }`. You should don't use retro versions like 4.1.1 published more as 4 years ago. It's the time when IE9 was just published and IE6-IE8 was used.

Comment: @user2695786: Can the usage of more deep CSS rule like `.ui-jqgrid .ChangeStyle { background-color: red; background-image: none }` fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following style and scripts

```
 <link type="text/css" href="http://jqueryrock.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />  
<link type="text/css" href="http://jqueryrock.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jqgrid/css/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />  
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryrock.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryrock.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js"></script>  
<script src="http://jqueryrock.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jqgrid/js/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script src="http://jqueryrock.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jqgrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

For More [style class in jqGrid Td using asp.net c#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rahul4_saxena/jqgrid-in-Asp-Net-C-Sharp/)

Comment: Have you refer the link which is mentioned

Comment: Have u used <table id="dataGrid" style="text-align: center;"></table>

Comment: if you want to style just td then add #dataGrid tr td { background-color: #e9e9e9: } in style

Comment: :) thanks dear if it helps. i will suggest you to refer how to design a table using css. Its very easy

Comment: you can use it it conditonally also like in your code you are using .addClass("dataGrid tr td");  and in style it will be .dataGrid tr td { background-color: #e9e9e9: }