# Set background color of cell in a column based on a particular condition in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

I want to change background colors(say,red) of all cells in a column(say, Total Sale) where column value is more than x(say, 10)? How can this be achieved.

Comment: Please show the code that you've already tried.

Comment: You need just use `cellattr` in the column. See [the old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12180842/315935) with [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/addclasstocolumn.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `formatter` for `total` column.

```
{
    name: "total",
    index: "total",
    formatter: function(cellvalue, options, rowObject){
        if(cellvalue>10)
            return '<span style="background-color: red; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; ">' + cellvalue + '</span>';
        else
            return cellvalue;
    }
}
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HJema/310/)