# jqGrid: jQuery - Add class to cell in row

Tags: jqgrid

How to add cell-red class to 'pesel' column in row?

```
{ name: 'pesel', index: 'pesel', width: 220, sortable: true, resizable: false},
{ name: 'differentpesel', index: 'differentpesel', hidden: true,  width: 100, sortable: true } 

                ],
               (...)
                afterInsertRow: function (rowid, rowdata, rowelem) {                  

                    if (rowdata.differentpesel == true) {
                       $('#' + rowid).children('td').addClass('cell-red');
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

One should use `cellattr` instead of `afterInsertRow`. It allows to add conditionally `class` or `style` attribute on some cells of specific column. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12180842/315935) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36969744/315935) for more details.