# How do set cell colors to a grid with frozen columns and groups?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

i have the following jqgrid 4.6 grid

[image]

the code for the grid:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/le-frog/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
  </head>
  <body>

    <table id="list47"></table>
    <div id="plist47"></div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.34/browser.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;
      $.jgrid.useJSON = true;
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function(){

        var mydata = [
          {id:"1",invdate:"2010-05-24",name:"test",note:"note",tax:"10.00",total:"2111.00"} ,
          {id:"2",invdate:"2010-05-25",name:"test2",note:"note2",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
          {id:"3",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"},
          {id:"4",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test",note:"note",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
          {id:"5",invdate:"2007-10-05",name:"test2",note:"note2",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
          {id:"6",invdate:"2007-09-06",name:"test3",note:"note3",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"},
          {id:"7",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test",note:"note",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
          {id:"8",invdate:"2007-10-03",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"21.00",total:"320.00"},
          {id:"9",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"},
          {id:"11",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
          {id:"12",invdate:"2007-10-02",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
          {id:"13",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"},
          {id:"14",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
          {id:"15",invdate:"2007-10-05",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
          {id:"16",invdate:"2007-09-06",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"},
          {id:"17",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
          {id:"18",invdate:"2007-10-03",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
          {id:"19",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"},
          {id:"21",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
          {id:"22",invdate:"2007-10-02",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
          {id:"23",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"},
          {id:"24",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
          {id:"25",invdate:"2007-10-05",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
          {id:"26",invdate:"2007-09-06",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"},
          {id:"27",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
          {id:"28",invdate:"2007-10-03",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
          {id:"29",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"}
        ];




        jQuery("#list47").jqGrid({
          data: mydata,
          datatype: "local",
          height: 'auto',
          rowNum: 30,
          rowList: [10,20,30],
          colNames:['Inv No','Date', 'Client', 'Amount','Tax','Total','Notes'],
          colModel:[
            {name:'id',index:'id', width:60, sorttype:"int"},
            {name:'invdate',index:'invdate', width:90, sorttype:"date", formatter:"date"},
            {name:'name',index:'name', width:100, editable:true},
            {name:'amount',index:'amount', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float", formatter:"number", editable:true},
            {name:'tax',index:'tax', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float", editable:true},
            {name:'total',index:'total', width:80,align:"right",sorttype:"float"},
            {name:'note',index:'note', width:150, sortable:false}
          ],
          pager: "#plist47",
          viewrecords: true,
          sortname: 'name',
          grouping:true,
          groupingView : {
            groupField : ['name'],
            groupColumnShow : [false],
            groupText : ['<b>{0} - {1} Item(s)</b>']
          },
          caption: "Configure group header row"
        });
      })

      jQuery("#list47").jqGrid('setGroupHeaders', {
        useColSpanStyle: false,
        groupHeaders:[
          {startColumnName: 'id', numberOfColumns: 2, titleText: 'Client Details'}
        ]
      });
      jQuery("#list47").jqGrid('setFrozenColumns');

    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

i want to do the following things to the grid:

1. Freeze columns InvoiceNo, Date and have other columns to the right scroll horizontally
2. i need to set individual cell colors to colors that matches certain
   conditions

**( A.)**
**Color the Amount columns cells who has a value 0.00 to 'red'. This means the code shoudl find all cells with value 0.00 in Amount column and color those cells to 'red'**

*please note that i dont need the whole row to be colored in red only just those cells with that matching value*

**( B. )**
**just like above, in the total column find the cells that has a value that is greater than 300.00 and color them in yellow**

how do i achieve this?

Comment: `cellattr` is the property/callback function of `colModel` (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:colmodel_options)) and not the option of the grid like `rowattr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should move the last part of your JavaScript code (where you call `setGroupHeaders` and `setFrozenColumns`) inside of `$(function(){...})` block.

To set the color/background-color of rows based on the value of `amount` you should use `rowattr`:

```js
rowattr: function (item) {
    if (item.amount == null || parseFloat(item.amount) === 0) {
        //return { "class": "ui-state-error" };
        //return { "style": "color: red" };
        return { "style": "background: red" };
    }
}
```

**See the demo here**: https://jsfiddle.net/f7yopLr0/1/. It produces the results like on the picture below

[image]

**UPDATED:** To change colors only the cells of `amount` and `total` columns one can use

```
cellattr: function (rowid, cellValue, item) {
    if (cellValue == null || parseFloat(cellValue) === 0) {
        return ' style="color:red"';
    }
}
```

in `amount` column and

```
cellattr: function (rowid, cellValue, item) {
    if (cellValue == null || parseFloat(cellValue) === 0) {
        return ' style="color:red"';
    }
}
```

in `total` column. See https://jsfiddle.net/f7yopLr0/2/

Comment: hi Oleg thanks for reply : ) that awesome. But Oleg i need to know if its possible to color only the cell that matches the condition NOT THE WHOLE ROW? e.g: if amount column cell has 0.00 it should be red so  only the cells in the column Amount with value 0.00 should be colored in red but not their whole row.

Comment: @ANP: Which cell? If you write about some cell then you should write about the column name which color/background color you need to change. I still don't know whether the color, background color or both you need to change. I posted you already references to old answers which demonstrates the usage of `rowattr` and `cellattr`. You need to use `cellattr`. See [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12180842/315935). One can set `class` or `style`, but one should use just a little another return value as in `rowattr`: one need return the string instead of object.

Comment: @ANP: Look at the demo https://jsfiddle.net/f7yopLr0/2/. I hope it do what you need. See **UPDATED** part of my answer.